# Access MovieClip in another method

Tags: flash, actionscript

```
var PlayerScore:TextField = new TextField();  

//Here we add the new textfield instance to the stage with addchild()  
_canvas.addChild(PlayerScore);  


var myFormat:TextFormat = new TextFormat();
myFormat.size = 30;

PlayerScore.defaultTextFormat = myFormat;

PlayerScore.text = _player_score.toString();
PlayerScore.width = 250;  
PlayerScore.x = 70;  
PlayerScore.y = -20;
PlayerScore.textColor = 0xFFFFFF;
```

I use this in my Constructor

How can I use

```
PlayerScore.text = _player_score.toString();
```

In another method?

Comment: what do you mean by "use"? you mean how you can set text from other method/class?

Comment: you could make it a static var

Comment: "you mean how you can set text from other method/class?" yes

Answer (score 0):

To use this method{
        PlayerScore.text = _player_score.toString();

assign a variable:example

```
    var cash:int = 500;  // cash is the variable//

    showTextBTN.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, variableTotext);

    function variableTotext(){
    Money.text = cash.toString();// the variable cash will output in Money text box
    }
```

Add a button or mc to stage, give it an instance name of "showTextBTN".
Then add a dynamic text box with instance name "Money".
add the above code in the actions timeline (as3);
Compile/ run movie